# How to make a field in a table null instead of zero if the float text box is empty in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, odata

I have developed an Asp.Net MVC 4 application in which I deal with few text boxes through which I enter the data into a sql table using knockout and OData. Now I have two text boxes which send float data to the database table and some times when I leave those text boxes empty, they take input as zero in the table and how can I make them NULL instead of zero when I leave them empty.

I have the following lines of code

**HTML**

```
<table class="addSection">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>

                <select data-bind="options: $root.productNames, optionsText: 'ProductName', optionsValue: 'ProductName', value: selectedChoice, optionsCaption: 'Product'">
                </select>
            </td>
           <td>

                <select data-bind="options: $root.termNames, optionsText: 'TermName', optionsValue: 'TermName', value: selectedTerm, optionsCaption: 'Term'">
                </select>
            </td>


             <td>

                <select data-bind="options: $root.locationNames, optionsText: 'LocationName', optionsValue: 'LocationName', value: selectedLocation, optionsCaption: 'Location'">
                </select>
            </td>

            <td>

                <select data-bind="options: $root.pipelineNames, optionsText: 'PipelineName', optionsValue: 'PipelineName', value: selectedPipeline, optionsCaption: 'Pipeline'">
                </select>
            </td>



             <td>

                <select data-bind="options: $root.indexNames, optionsText: 'IndexName', optionsValue: 'IndexName', value: selectedIndex, optionsCaption: 'Index'">
                </select>
            </td>

            <td>

                <select data-bind="options: $root.counterpartyNames, optionsText: 'CounterPartyName', optionsValue: 'CounterPartyName', value: selectedBidCounterParty, optionsCaption: 'Bid CP'">
                </select>
            </td>

            <td>

                <select data-bind="options: $root.counterpartyNames, optionsText: 'CounterPartyName', optionsValue: 'CounterPartyName', value: selectedOfferCounterParty, optionsCaption: 'Offer CP'">
                </select>
            </td>

            <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Bid Volume"  data-bind="value: bidVolume" />
            </td>

              <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Bid" data-bind="value: bid" />
            </td>

              <td>
                <input type="text"  placeholder="Offer" data-bind="value: offer" />
            </td>

              <td>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Offer Volume" data-bind="value: offerVolume" />
            </td>

            <td >
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-bind="click: add, enable: selectedChoice" value="Add New Entry" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

**Knockout Js and OData**

```
 self.selectedChoice = ko.observable();
    self.selectedTerm = ko.observable();
    self.selectedLocation = ko.observable();
    self.selectedPipeline = ko.observable();
    self.selectedIndex = ko.observable();
    self.selectedBidCounterParty = ko.observable();
    self.selectedOfferCounterParty = ko.observable();
    self.optionsValue = ko.observable();

    self.bidVolume = ko.observable();
    self.bid = ko.observable();
    self.offer = ko.observable();
    self.offerVolume = ko.observable();


    self.add = function (canadiancrude) {
        var payload = {
            Term: this.selectedTerm(), Product: this.selectedChoice(), Location: this.selectedLocation(), Pipeline: this.selectedPipeline(),
            BidCP: this.selectedBidCounterParty(), BidVolume: this.bidVolume(), Index: this.selectedIndex(), Bid: this.bid(), Offer: this.offer(),
            OfferVolume: this.offerVolume(), OfferCP: this.selectedOfferCounterParty(), Locked: false, Sequence: "", TermID: 0
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: '/odata/Canadiancrudes',
            type: 'POST',
            //  data: ko.toJSON(payload),
            data: JSON.stringify(payload),
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    }
```

In the above HTML Table Bid and Offer are Floats and remaining fields are string, when ever I leave the string controls empty they consider it as null but when I leave float controls empty, they take zero as the input.
May I know a better way to deal with this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had another idea while lunching - perhaps, if my other answer doesn't work, simply changing the type of your bid property definition in the .cs model to nullable would do the trick. For example, since I don't know what your models look like. There might be a better way do do this, for example modifying the "Model Binder" that odata uses...this might not be a knockout question at all.

```
public float Bid {get;set;}
```

should then be

```
public float? Bid {get;set;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a computed in your viewmodel for your float datatypes.

```
self._bid = ko.observable();
self.bid = ko.computed({
  read:function() { 
    return self._bid ();
  },write:function(val) { 
    if(val === "") { 
      val = null;
    }
    self._bid(val);
  }})
```

or,

```
var nullIfEmptyObs = function(initialValue) {
  var store = ko.observable(initialValue);
  return ko.computed({
      read:function() { 
        return store();
      },write:function(val) { 
        if(val === "") { 
          val = null;
        }
        store(val);
      }});
  }
self.bid = nullIfEmptyObs(null);
```

Comment: Thanks and how do I send the computed value to my add function in the view model?

Comment: The exact same way you do already. self.bid is a read/write computed observable, which behaves exactly like a real observable. So you don't have to change anything, just reference it like `self.bid()`

Comment: If you have a js file with custom bindings, or extensions or your own utilities, put the nullifemptyobs in there like this `ko.nullIfEmptyObs = function(initialValue) { //rest of function here };` and then reference in your viewmodels like the code: `self.bid = ko.nullIfEmptyObs()`. Make sure that snippet is loaded after knockout has been loaded though.